# Scale and center image on hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, transform

I am designing user guides for my company and need to find a better way to view the images. I have got scaling on hover to work fine, but this will only work properly if the user has a large computer screen when viewing the image. I therefore want to center the image on hover.

In addition it would be lovely to let the image scale in relation to the window size. I have bootstrap and jQuery is linked.

My code for it at this moment

```css
     .thumbnail {
        transition: transform .5s, left .5s; /* Animation */
     margin: 0 auto;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
       @media (min-width: 1600px) { 
       .thumbnail:hover {
     transform: scale(1.75);
    
    }}
       
       @media (max-width: 1600px) { 
       .thumbnail:hover {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        position: relative;
        left: 25%;
    
    }}
```

```html
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="thumbnail" style="width:800px; height:auto">
```

[The big problem is the side menu who is part of the template on the business website. Click this link to see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ven4H.png)

Comment: why are you using left: 25% ?

Comment: If I didn't change the position at all the image would scale up and out of the window on mobile phones

Answer (score 0):

Use the object-fit property for the img

```
.thumbnail {
 object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: object fit is a good solution, i agree, however the drawback is that IE doesnt support it and it's partially supported on edge. This means OP has to think about how to solve that problem as well. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: Check q for updated info. object-fit would probably work fine on a site without a sidebar

Comment: Problem is that object-fit resizes the image to fit its container, but since there is a separate container on the right-hand side, it will resize to fit the content container and not the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't link bootstrap and jquery please first link them.Within style tag replace your current code with this.(this is responsive as well).

```
<style>   
.zoom {
    padding: 50px;
    transition: transform .2s; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    border :none;
}

.zoom:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2); 
    }
</style>
```

And add "zoom" to your class in img tag.

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="thumbnail zoom" style="width:800px; height:auto">
```

Comment: This is almost the same as I already use, but it didn't help the image stay inside the windows... It works great for the scale part, but the image is still outside of the frame.

Comment: im using chrome devTools for check responsive. It worked perfectly in chrome devTools.

Comment: check the image I linked in the q. It shows that this probably work normally, but because of the template on the site everything is pushed a little to the left.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.thumb-div {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .thumb-div img {
    -webkit-transition: ease all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: ease all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: ease all 0.3s;
    transition: ease all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  
  .thumb-div:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
    transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
  }
```

```html
<div class="thumb-div">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" title="" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain how does it solve OP's issue. Posting code only is not enough.

Comment: I have modified code. check now it's working proper.